# Can I embed or serve a built React app within another React-Router app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a personal website/portfolio built with ReactJS and React-Router. I want to be able to serve separately developed and built ReactJS apps as my coding demos from within my personal website (rather than provide an external link). I have used Create-React-App to bootstrap the original website app.

I have tried placing the built files (index.html and *.js files) in the public folder, which is copied to the /build folder when the app is built. However, these files are not being served.

Interestingly it was working with the React development server, but stopped working after building and serving with the npm 'serve' module.

eg. I have copied the built demo app to

```
/public/demo-builds/[app-name]/
```

and this gets copied when building the main website app as

```
/build/demo-builds/[app-name]/
```

Accessing `my-domain-name.com/demo-builds/[app-name]` or  `my-domain-name.com/demo-builds/[app-name]/index.html` results in error.

Is this an issue with my overall methodology of trying to serve separate built apps within a react-router app?

Is there an accepted way to serve built React apps within a React app?

Comment: I think serving them individually would be easier to maintain, but can you provide the error you're receiving when you try to access `my-domain-name.com/demo-builds/[app-name]`?

Comment: Update: the demo app now works if I access `my-domain-name.com/demo-builds/[app-name]/index.html`

Comment: The 'error' I receive is in custom routing to a 404 page with react-router. Until I find a better solution I'll update my links to the demo app to include `/index.html`